# Space is not coming when formatting string in php

Tags: php, string, string-formatting

When I am using `printf`, I am not being able to give space.

This is my code:

```
$number1=12.30;
$number2=1;
$f_number1 = sprintf("%9.2f",$number1);
$f_number2 = sprintf("%9.2f",$number2);
echo $f_number1;
echo $f_number2;
```

I am getting simple this:

```
12.30
1.00
```

And I want this instead:

```
    12.30
     1.00
```

Notice that there are spaces before the numbers.

Now when I do this:

```
printf("%'x9.2f", $number1);
```

then I am getting x instead of space. Like this:

```
xxxx12.30
```

My question is how to get space instead of x?

Thank you in advance,
Vivid

Comment: You're viewing it in a browser right ? Browsers only show one space even if there is several spaces. Use `&nbsp;` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code .. you are just displaying it in html instead of text format

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");
printf("%9.2f\n", 12.30);
printf("%9.2f", 1.00);
```

[Online Demo](http://eval.in/32472)

For HTML then use `&nbsp;` with `str_pad` instead

Comment: Hey! Thank you for a quick response but would you elaborate your answer a little bit. I am new to this and I don't understand many things. What do you mean by "displaying it in html"? If I have to show this in my website, won't I have to display it in html? And where should I put that 'header("content-type:text/plain");' in my php file?

Comment: `header("Content-type: text/plain");` is just for you to see the output ... since you are developing a web application use str_pad instead

Comment: OK. thanks. Got it. and understood what was the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

use html `pre` tag. Preformatted text.

```
<pre>
<?php
$number1=12.30;
$number2=1;
$f_number1 = sprintf("%9.2f\n",$number1);
$f_number2 = sprintf("%9.2f",$number2);
echo $f_number1;
echo $f_number2;
?>
</pre>
```